# Getting failed to open stream error while uploading images

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have folder structure year/month/day. I need to upload image in the directory of year/month/day for e.g 2016/03/08/example.jpg.

### Here is my code

```
 public function UpdateImage(Request $request){

        $year = date("Y");
        $year = public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.$year;

        if(!file_exists ($year)){
            $month = date("m");
            $month = $year."/".$month;
            if(!file_exists ($year)){
                mkdir($month, 0777, true);
                chmod($year, 0777);
                chmod($month, 0777);
            }

            $day = date("d");
            $day = public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.date("Y")."/".date("m")."/".date("d");

            if(!file_exists ($day)){
                mkdir($day, 0777, true);
                chmod($day, 0777);
            }
        }else{
            $month = date("m");
            $month = public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.date("Y")."/".date("m");
            if(!file_exists ($month)){
                mkdir($month, 0777, true);
                chmod($year, 0777);
                chmod($month, 0777);
            }

            $day = date("d");
            $day = public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.date("Y")."/".date("m")."/".date("d");

            if(!file_exists ($day)){
                mkdir($day, 0777, true);
                chmod($day, 0777);
            }
        }
        $url = public_path().'/upload/userimage/'.date("Y")."/".date("m")."/".date("d");

        $data = $_POST['imageData'];
        $userIdx = $_POST['id'];
        $delImage = DB::table('user')->where('UserIdx', $userIdx)->first();
        $filename = $url.$delImage->PhotoFilePathName;

        if(file_exists($filename)){
            //unlink($filename);
        }

        $imageName =  date("Y")."/".date("m")."/".date("d")."/".hash('ripemd160', time()).'.png';

        DB::table('user')
            ->where('UserIdx', $userIdx)
            ->update(array('PhotoFilePathName' => $imageName));

        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        file_put_contents($url, $data);

    }
```

but I am getting this error to upload image.

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/sitename/public/upload/userimage/2016/03/08): failed to open stream: Is a directory.
```

Please help to solve this problem and review my code.

Comment: You are giving the path to save without the file name. Concatenate the image name to url: `file_put_contents($url.'/'.$imageName, $data);`.

Comment: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/projectname/public/upload/userimage/2016/03/08/2016/03/08/c476d5d507c07fabac9fd275ca606d835c4d5162.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are giving folder path to `file_put_contents` you can solve this by giving it the file path instead. However there are other areas which you can improve your functions too, for example the folder creation process, The third parameter you provide to the mkdir is for recursive folder creation, you don't need to create year/month/day dir seprately if you use that flag. Try following code it will solve your problems with the function:

```
    public function UpdateImage(Request $request){
        $folderPath = '';

        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');
        $day = date('d');

        $folderPath = $year . "/" . $month . "/" . $day;

        $baseUrl = public_path().'/upload/userimage/';
        if(!file_exists ($baseUrl . $folderPath)) {
            mkdir($baseUrl . $folderPath, 0777, true);
            chmod($baseUrl . $year, 0777);
            chmod($baseUrl . $month, 0777);
            chmod($baseUrl . $day, 0777);
        }

        $data = $_POST['imageData'];
        $userIdx = $_POST['id'];
        $delImage = DB::table('user')->where('UserIdx', $userIdx)->first();
        $filename = $baseUrl.$delImage->PhotoFilePathName;

        if(file_exists($filename)){
            //unlink($filename);
        }

        $imageName =  $folderPath . "/" . hash('ripemd160', time()).'.png';

        DB::table('user')
            ->where('UserIdx', $userIdx)
            ->update(array('PhotoFilePathName' => $imageName));

        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        file_put_contents($baseUrl . $imageName, $data);
    }
```